# Splunk query to filter results

Tags: splunk

I have some code deployed on 1 out of my 6 servers. I need a splunk query that pulls data from the other 5 hosts. Something like - All except this 1 host. I know the host option in splunk to look for the host's logs, but I have no idea how to do all except 1. Can someone please assist me?

The one box I am talking about has my latest code changes, and the other 5 have my old code. So I want to write a query to do a before vs after analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have your answer, but I use an alternative method that speeds things up for me.

Within your search results, you can quickly eliminate what you want to filter out by **ALT-clicking** on a value in a selected field. In your case, it would add `NOT host="1"` to your query and immediately update your results.

I find this particularly helpful when I'm in the preliminary stage of investigating an issue, and don't have enough information to know exactly where to look first. It makes it easy to rapidly eliminate what you don't need.

*Note: This may still be broken in Splunk 6, not sure if the bug has been fixed yet: http://answers.splunk.com/answers/109473/alt-click-not-working-selected-fields

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got the answer to my question. Just use !=. So if I want the results for all my hosts except host 1, all I do is - index=blah host!="1"